# getting online openstreetmap view in android

Tags: android, openlayers, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am currently trying to get an online map view of openstreet map in to an Android application. But I am unable to find any tutorials which explains on how to do that. Can someone help me on how to do it? Or give me some suggestions. I have found some applications like osmdroid but it uses embeded map. Not online one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[osmdrid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) is a library you can use in your own app.  It is a tile besed rather than vector based solution.  It supports online as well as offline maps.  There are examples availible and some documentation as well as a discussion groupe bug tracker etc. check the project page.

There is a very good list of libraries to help with OpenStreetMap on the on the [OpenStreetMap web pages](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks).